# Hadoop not suitable for distributed processing across many sites?

Tags: hadoop, distributed-computing, grid-computing

I've read a few articles suggesting that Hadoop is only really designed to work on a cluster at a single physical location, not for a number of widely distributed nodes (e.g. running a distributed cluster over the internet from multiple sites).

Does anyone have any real experience trying to use Hadoop across mutliple sites? What kind of issues will I run into? Or am I better to just go with a different framework (e.g. BOINC).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's any difference between executing on a set of relatively local nodes vs on a set of widely distributed nodes it would be in the increased time required to move large amounts of data back and forth between nodes.  If you have a problem that involves crunching, aggregating and joining large amounts of data then you will necessarily be sending large amounts of data between your nodes.  That means that no matter what platform you choose (hadoop, storm, etc) you will have to deal with this issue.  BOINC or some other volunteer-based system may be cheaper, but your implementation will still be hit with high data transfer costs.  Furthermore, you'll likely introduce node heterogeneity into the mix which will make your implementation even more interesting to develop and debug.

And by the way, hadoop and BOINC are two very different animals solving very different problems.

Comment: Good point about Hadoop issues on heterogeneous machines - I'll do some more research. WRT your point about the data transfers being the key difference between a co-located cluster and a distributed one, I understand that's always going to be the case. I guess my underlying question though was whether Hadoop is much worse than other distributed platforms for this? (ie. does it have very chatty internal protocols for data distribution etc?).

Comment: Are the protocol chatty?  I have no idea, but I'd be surprised if any heavily-used open source platform would be overly chatty.

Comment: Without a definitve answer to that question, you may want to look at the [comparison here](http://www.jppf.org/forums/index.php?topic=790.0), with another grid computing platform. More than the results, I believe the questions asked and methodology used to answer them are very insightful

Comment: Thanks for the link, Lolo - hadnt come across JPPF, but looks very promising.